# What is the equivalent of ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues for EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using this

```
 _obj.Entry(update).CurrentValues.SetValues(update);
```

but it is not working not updating

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent. The closest is something like this:

```
var existing = context.Set<YourEntityType>().Find(update.Id); // pass your entity PK
if (existing == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(); // something is wrong
context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(update);
```

Basically you locate the existing entity with `Find` method, which will either locate it in the local cache or retrieve it from the database. In both cases you will end up with entity instance attached to the context. Then you update that instance with the values from the passed object.